# How to get column width of a Win32 listbox?

Tags: winapi, listbox, width, multiple-columns

I have a Win32 multicolumn listbox:

```
HWND hListBox = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TEXT("LISTBOX"), NULL, LBS_MULTICOLUMN | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY, 0, 25, 600, 450, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I add items like this:

```
SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)("New items"));
```

After I add some items into hListBox, columns width changed.
How can I get the new **width of first column** of this listbox? Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LB_GETITEMRECT` message for that:

```
RECT rc;
SendMessage(hWndLB, LB_GETITEMRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rc);
int iItemWidth = rc.right - rc.left;
```